# Modify AMS theoremstyles using tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, conditionals, amsthm

The `amsthm` package has predefined theoremstyles: plain,definition,remark. I would like to modify each style using `tcolorbox`. For instance, if a theorem environment is created using the `\newtheorem` command in the plain style, then it gets a green background. If it is created in the definition style, then it gets a yellow background. One could try to redefine the `\newtheorem` command and replace it with `\newtcbtheorem`, but this has to happen according to the currently selected theoremstyle. I played around with the `ifthen` package, but could not make things work.

Comment: Can you clarify your constraints? What you want to do (define a theorem style that mimics the ams style but with colors) is not too hard using tcolorbox or thmtools. So I am led to believe that you are trying to achieve the desired output with specific constraints on how the solution must be implemented. Can you make this clear?

Comment: Here are the constraints: I want to create a package that -- when loaded -- modifies the standard amsthm styles (in the way described above), but so that the document compiles just fine when the package is not loaded.